# Using react-native-svg-charts how to set x-axis and y-axis value in bar chart , whereas y-axis is related to time and x-axis is related to numbers?

Tags: react-native

```
 DataSet Using =  "Time": [
            {
                "Hr": 15,
                "Number": 100,
                "Min": 0,
            },
            {
                "Hr": 22,
                "Number": 70,
                "Min": 0,

            },
            {
                "Hr": 0,
                "Number": 50,
                "Min": 0,

            },
            {
                "Hr": 5,
                "Number": 70,
                "Min": 0,

            },
            {
                "Hr": 6,
                "Number": 100,
                "Min": 0,

            }
        ]

const data1 = [
        {
           hr: '15:00',

        },
        {
            hr: '19:45',

        },
        {

            hr: '00:30',

        },
        {

            hr: '05:15',

        },
        {

            hr: '10:00',

        },


    ]

 Code 
                       <View style={{ height: 150, flexDirection: 'row', flex: 1 }}>
                            <YAxis
                                style={{ paddingLeft: 15 }}
                                data={data}
                                yAccessor={({ item }) => item.number}
                                contentInset={{ top: 40, bottom: 40 }}
                                svg={{
                                    fill: 'grey',
                                    fontSize: 10,
                                }}
                                numberOfTicks={2}
                                scale={scale.scaleBand}
                                formatLabel={(_, index) => data[index].number}

                            />
                            <BarChart style={{ width: 350, marginLeft: 5 }}
                                data=Time
                                svg={{ fill }}
                                contentInset={{ top: 30, bottom: 0 }}

                                numberOfTicks={3}
                                yAccessor={({ item }) => item.number}
                            >
                                <Grid />
                            </BarChart>
                        </View>
                        <XAxis

                            data={data1}

                            svg={{ fontSize: 10, fill: 'black' }}
                            scale={scale.scaleBand}
                            formatLabel={(_, index) => data1[index].label}

                        />
                    </View>
```

Which looks exactly the way i dont want .In my bar chart x-axis is always static value ,Which consist of  data1 values represents hr and y-axis consist of numbers starts always from 0 to 100, ex 0,50,100.In bar chart when i am passing hr =15 it should go till 100 and then end till 22 hr starts and goes on,please suggest if any one can help?